# Build cross compiler - error: libmpfr not found

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

I am trying to build a cross compiler. I follow this tutorial: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

I installed binutils in in /opt/cross. now I try to install gcc-4.7.4 with mpfr-2.4.2. I used commands to prepare and configure:

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"

mv gmp-4.3.2 gcc-4.7.4/gmp
mv mpfr-2.4.2 gcc-4.7.4/mpfr
mv mpc-0.8.1 gcc-4.7.4/mpc

# i am in usr/src directory
mkdir build-gcc
cd build-gcc

../gcc-4.7.4/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
```

Now, i use `make all-gcc` to build, but I receive following error: `configure: error: libmpfr not found or uses a different ABI (including static vs shared).`

Why is this happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [croostool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) or even [Buildroor](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)? These projects will take care of toolchain creation.

Comment: You should get the config.log that corresponds to that configure error, it might be buried inside some subdirectory. That will aid in pinning down the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check how "configure" checks if libmpfr is available (where configure looks for it) or just give the path to your libmpfr - with probably --enable-libmpfr=/path/ or something like this.

The second option is to give gcc configure option to disable using of mpfr (--disable-mpfr ?)

I assume that you are trying to compile gcc for another architecture than your host. Maybe gcc configure found libmpfr but it is mpfr from your host and not from your target architecture? You may take a look into config.log file if there is any and check which mpfr is using by configure.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to link libraries with **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./gcc-4.7.4/mpfr/.libs**