# Error while compiling GCC-7.2

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am getting this error while compiling GCC pass 2 for Linux from scratch.

```
    configure: summary of build options:

  Version:           GNU MP 6.1.2
  Host type:         none-pc-linux-gnu
  ABI:               standard
  Install prefix:    /tools
  Compiler:          x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
  Static libraries:  yes
  Shared libraries:  no

make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-7.2.0/build'
Makefile:900: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When i make (just typed make again) again without changing or re configuring anything im getting different error.

```
configure: error: libmpfr not found or uses a different ABI (including static vs shared).
Makefile:5232: recipe for target 'configure-mpc' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-mpc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-7.2.0/build'
Makefile:900: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

im following [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/gcc-pass2.html) guide. Configs are:

```
CC=$LFS_TGT-gcc                                    \
CXX=$LFS_TGT-g++                                   \
AR=$LFS_TGT-ar                                     \
RANLIB=$LFS_TGT-ranlib                             \
../configure                                       \
    --prefix=/tools                                \
    --with-local-prefix=/tools                     \
    --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include \
    --enable-languages=c,c++                       \
    --disable-libstdcxx-pch                        \
    --disable-multilib                             \
    --disable-bootstrap                            \
    --disable-libgomp
```

Using following versions of mpfr, gmp, mpc

```
mpfr-4.0.0 
gmp-6.1.2 
mpc-1.1.0
```

Comment: What was the error from the compiler? this isn't enough of the report. Capture your `stderr` and `stdout` when you make, and look for the error there.

Comment: when i make again without changing or re-configuring anything im getting different error.

Comment: Try `make clean` and `make clean all` before. Failing that, download into a clean directory, and try there.

Comment: @kabanus not working !

Comment: I missed the new error - that's something we can work with. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831680/build-cross-compiler-error-libmpfr-not-found#25832082 help?

Comment: Getting another error " ../../gcc/system.h:221:11: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory" compilation terminated

Comment: Look for algorithm.*  in your gcc download directory. Make sure the headers and library are included in your configuration (the make file `-I` and `-l` flags.

Comment: Another question. Did you run `./configure`?

Comment: yes i ran ./configure with all flags as mentioned in the guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with **mpfr** and **mpc** version. While downloading them I had an error and later i downloaded wrong version by mistake. (m*ost of the newbies will make this mistake, because some of the link in LFS book are broken, So double check for broken links and download correct version*) I have changed it to correct version as mentioned in LFS. After recompiling, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This is an important note in most `gcc` build tutorials:

> First, we highly recommend that GCC be built into a separate directory
>   from the sources which does not reside within the source tree. This is
>   how we generally build GCC; building where srcdir == objdir should
>   still work, but doesn’t get extensive testing; building where objdir
>   is a subdirectory of srcdir is unsupported.

Furthermore, in one walkthrough (I can't find it now, maybe later) it's explicitly stated **you can't run configure from the same directory it resides in.**

Assuming you have a folder "srcdir=/path/to/parent/srcdir" then the recommended way to start configure the build is:

```
cd /path/to/parent
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$srcdir/configure
```

This is written here: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html.

The entire doc on installing is https://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: i have compiled it in anew separate directory named "build"

Comment: i was running this on KALI LINUX, i changed the distro to LINUX MINT started everything from first. now its working. thanks for the help.